# Orthogonal matrices question

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Define
$$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos t & \sin t & 0 \\
-\sin t & \cos t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \pm 1  
\end{pmatrix}:t ∈\mathbb R\right\}$$

a) Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $O(3)$, the group of orthogonal $3 \times 3$
matrices.
[Hint: For this you must show that each matrix is orthogonal, and that G
satisfies the subgroup properties]

b) Let $S^2$ be the sphere in $R^3$ defined by

$$ S^2 = \{x ∈ R^3,\ |x| = 1\} $$

Show that $G$ acts on $S^2$ using the standard matrix action on a vector.

c) Show that the orbit of $(1, 0, 0) \in S^2$ under the action of G is the set

$$ \{(\cos t, \sin t, 0),\ t \in [0, 2\pi)\}$$

and sketch a picture of this set inside $S^2$.

d) Find the orbit of $(0, 0, 1) \in S^2$ under the action of $G$. Again sketch a picture of the orbit inside $S^2$.

e) Describe all the remaining orbits of the action of $G$ on $S^2$
, sketch a picture of them.

I've found an example question but I have no idea how to do it at all, also if anyone can explain step by step will be helpful as I'm not good on this topic and am trying to understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know *at least* what must be proved in each part?! Say, what must you do to show the given set is *a group*? This is a second year (at least) stuff question, you must know something...

Comment: Since there are so many users here, you are bound to find someone sufficiently bored as to throw in some useful hints for your homework; however, in general, questions such as yours are not very well received in this site, because they reek of "do my homework" stench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part a): there is a hint. Show that a matrix $A$ in $G$ is orthogonal, i.e. it satisfies $^tAA = id$. $G$ is a subgroup of $O(3)$ if and only if $AB^{-1} \in O(3)$ for any $A,B \in O(3)$ - general characterization of subgroups.

Part b): prove that $||Ax|| = 1$ if $A \in O(3)$ and $x \in S^2$. Hint: evaluate $||Ax||^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle$. In this way the action
$$\theta \colon G \times S^2 \rightarrow S^2: (A,x) \mapsto Ax $$
is well defined - check it satisfies the axioms of action.

Part c) and d): just perform the standard product between a matrix in $G$ and $(1,0,0), (0,0,1)$ and see what you get. As $t$ varies you will see the orbits.

Part e): use part c) and d) + usual multiplication between a matrix and a vector.